# Scroll top with navigation background color is not working

Tags: jquery, html, scrolltop

I am trying to create single page website. check [my example](http://rankairos.webs.com/)

Here, while `click` on scroll `Top`,   After `click` on any navigation except **home** ,
its showing the same navigation (only in background color).
But I need the home navigation (background color) while click on scroll `Top`

**Example**

click on **about me** navigation, then click on scroll `Top` 
its not changing the a link `active` `background color`

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use :

```
$('#back-top a').click(function() {
  $('#nav > li.active').removeClass('active');
  $('#nav > li:first').addClass('active');
});
```

And add this CSS style :

```
li.active {
    background-color: #eee;
}
```

Regarding your needs (scrolling background on menu items), I really suggest that you take a look at : http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/how-to-build-a-lava-lamp-style-navigation-menu/

Comment: Thank you for your reply. but i need to change the background color of active link.

Comment: This is nice. thank you.. 
Is there any way to do this smoothly.. I will explain  you clearly,
If my navigation is in about me session and i click on scroll top then it has to move through portfolio and last reach home.

Don't mind please!

Comment: I've added a tutorial that fits your needs (at least, I guess :))

Answer (score 1):

Use `background-attachment: fixed;` for your `<body>` element.

i.e.

```
body {
    background:#000000 url(../images/body.jpg) no-repeat;
    font-size:14px;
    background-attachment: fixed; /* new */
}
```

Comment: Thank you for a new idea. 
But my question is not related to that. please go to my link and see the example also.

Answer (score 1):

Add those two lines to your top link click event:

```
$('#back-top a').click(function() {
  $('#nav li.active').removeClass('active');
  $('#nav li').first().addClass('active');
}
```

But there must be a way to do this with the pagescroller api.

**Edit:**
Just took a look at the api at http://pagescroller.com/documentation/
There is a way to do this but only with the pro version of pagescroller.
Another solution could be to call the prev() function of pagescroller several times.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. but i need to change the background color of active link. Normally its working fine. i have problem with scroll top  and active link background color